# Textbox value doesn't get updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, textbox

I have a asp.net page with a datalist with a textbox and a button on it, on page load the textbox gets text in it, if I change the text and press the button the text doesn't get updated.

What am I doing wrong?

```
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable table = CategoryAccess.GetProducts();

        ProductList.DataSource = table;
        ProductList.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = textbox.Text;

    CategoryAccess.UpdateProducts(Name);
}
}
```

Comment: Is there additional code missing here.  Are you explicitly setting the text of the text box. If so, this will wipe out changes by the time you get to the btn_Click event.

Comment: I am a bit lost here, can you show the .aspx code and also where's the categoryaccess links to? a sql table or what?

Comment: I made the code shorter to make it easy to see, it has to be here the problem is, there is no problem with the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I found that I put `textbox.text = "xxx"` in `Page_Load()` but outside `if(!ispostback)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [**EnableViewState**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx) property in your textBox control and set the value to `true`.

e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1"
             EnableViewState="true"
             MaxLength="25"
             runat="server"/>
```

or you can do it programatically:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.EnableViewState = true;
}
```

Comment: Dosent work, if I change: textbox.text = "hello"; 
string Name = textbox.Text; the value get updated to hello. It's like the textbox dosent notice that the text is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bing again the new data...

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = textbox.Text;

    // you update with the new parametre
    CategoryAccess.UpdateProducts(Name);

    // you get the new data
    DataTable table = CategoryAccess.GetProducts();

    // and show it
    ProductList.DataSource = table;
    ProductList.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Still the same, the database value is still the same even if I show the new value on the page. I havent mentioned that I cant see the textbox inside the datalist, becouse its in a datalist  so I use this to get the textbox value:                                                                                                                                foreach (DataListItem di in ProductList.Items)
        {
            textbox.Text = (((TextBox)(di.FindControl("textbox"))).Text);
        }